# Node / Socket.io - Setting cookies server-side when using sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, cookies, socket.io

I want to be able to modify a user's cookies server-side in response to a socket event coming from the client.

Essentially mimicking a cookie's placement during a request-response cycle. Like so:

```
res.cookie('rememberme', '1', { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000), httpOnly: true });
```

But, since I'm using sockets I'm assuming the response object can't be used the same way.

Question:

What is standard way to set/update a cookie serverside when using socket.io?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the closest thing you would get to a "standard" is really a "best practice", and that would likely come from the library's [author](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace#use(fn:function):namespace). Also, based on your post, it's unclear if you intend to modify the cookies midway in the socket interaction or just set initially. I don't think the former is possible without reestablishing the connection. With that in mind, you could set cookies via sockets in the "handshake" phase. As of socket.io v1, it is a best practice to use a middleware like so:

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {

  // cookie information is contained here: socket.request
  // manipulate it as you see fit

  next();
});
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: From all my searching you are probably right about the handshake phase being the only place. I was hoping since the request object and cookies were still accessible with socket.io that  it would probably also be possible to access the response object or at least a way modify the response headers. Shame, I liked using cookies to hold a little of the client state to avoid database fetches.